# WebService did't accept request format

Tags: java, android, web-services, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I have a web service, on which i'd like to access the ping method. this method simply takes a string and returns a string.

I want to access it with the ksoap2 library on an android device. After many days of failing to achieve the right result i found out with SoapUI that my request has to look as followed:

```
// Generated with SoapUI
<v:Envelope xmlns:ns="http://shared.bimserver.org/" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <v:Header />
  <v:Body>
    <ns:ping>
      <in>test</in>
    </ns:ping>
  </v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

This is my code:

```
String namespace = "http://shared.bimserver.org/";
String method = "ping";
String url = "http://10.0.0.5:8082/soap?WSDL";

SoapObject request = new SoapObject(namespace, method);
request.addProperty("in", "test");

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
```

And this is the request generated by my code.

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <v:Header />
  <v:Body>
    <ping xmlns="http://shared.bimserver.org/">
      <in i:type="d:string">test</in>
    </ping>
  </v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

I found out that the web service did't like line 4

```
<ping xmlns="http://shared.bimserver.org/">
```

It should be formated like the above (working) request generated with soapUI. Somehow the web service don't likes the namespace to be defined directly in the ping tag. 
However. With my code I get following response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"http://shared.bimserver.org/", local:"in"). Expected elements are &lt;{}in></faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

So how do i get the namespace from the ping tag up to the envelope tag?